# HTTP 103 Responses: What happens if a server sends a 103 early hints response to a client that does not support it? Is it backwards compatible?

Tags: http, httpresponse, http2, response-headers

The HTTP response code 103 is designed for sending "early hints" to browsers about assets they can begin fetching while waiting for the full HTML page to be generated.

My question is this: how safe and compatible is it to use this type of response? Should you only send this response to clients who indicate that they support it? What will old clients do with this response code? Will some of them assume that this is actually the final response, and then completely miss the HTML coming later?

I couldn't find much information online about potential compatibility issues.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging I discovered the [IETF RFC document on response code 103](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8297) which has this to say about compatibility:

> Some clients might have issues handling a 103 (Early Hints) response,
> because informational responses are rarely used in reply to requests
> not including an Expect header field ([RFC7231], Section 5.1.1).
>
> In particular, an HTTP/1.1 client that mishandles an informational
> response as a final response is likely to consider all responses to
> the succeeding requests sent over the same connection to be part of
> the final response.  Such behavior might constitute a cross-origin
> information disclosure vulnerability in case the client multiplexes
> requests to different origins onto a single persistent connection.
>
> Therefore, a server might refrain from sending 103 (Early Hints)
> responses over HTTP/1.1 unless the client is known to handle
> informational responses correctly.
>
> HTTP/2 clients are less likely to suffer from incorrect framing since
> handling of the response header fields does not affect how the end of
> the response body is determined.

So basically **it's safer to only use this over HTTP/2, and do so very cautiously over HTTP/1.1**.

Would still be useful to hear from anyone who has had real-world experience with deploying this technique and any compatibility issues discovered.